# No auto resize of yaxis of highcharts in shiny

Tags: r, highcharts, shiny, rcharts

I would like to include a highchart plot that automatically resizes its y-axis when groups are selected or deselected into a shiny application.

The following plot works fine in the viewer pane of Rstudio

```
library(rCharts)
dat <- data.frame(expand.grid(group = letters[1:3], x = letters[4:6]), y = c(0.1,1:8))
hPlot(x = "x", y = "y", groups = "group", data = dat, type = "line")
```

but it does not work, when I include it into a shiny application:

```
library(shiny)
runApp(shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    mainPanel(showOutput("h", 'highcharts'))
  ), 
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$h <- renderChart2({ 
      dat <- data.frame(expand.grid(group = letters[1:3], x = letters[4:6]),
                        y = c(0.1,1:8))
      hPlot(x = "x", y = "y", groups = "group", data = dat, type = "line")
    })
  }
))
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to a clash between the version of highcharts running and the version of jquery. Shiny is using a later version of jquery. When you call highcharts outside shiny jquery 1.9.1 is being used. The error in the console when shiny is ran and a series is removed/added is

```
TypeError: invalid 'in' operand style
```

The version of highcharts is `Highcharts JS v3.0.1 (2013-04-09)`. It maybe necessary to use a more uptodate version of highcharts as suggested http://forum.highcharts.com/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=22040

Referenced as a known bug on highcharts https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1890

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can you tell me how to use a newer version of Highcharts in a shiny application?

Comment: You can use `options(rcharts.cdn = TRUE)` to instruct rCharts to use the cdn defined in the yaml file associated with the highcharts library so https://github.com/ramnathv/rCharts/blob/master/inst/libraries/highcharts/config.yml that should use an uptodate highcharts.

Comment: Wow, I didn't expect it to be so simple. It works fine! Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, the solution didn't work when the shiny app is hosted on www.shinyapps.io. What worked for me is downloading the highcharts.js, putting it into the www subfolder of my shiny project, and including `tags$head(tags$script(src="highcharts.js"))` into my shinyUI.