# Highcharts stickyTracking

Tags: r, highcharts, shiny, rcharts

I am trying to use R shiny with the following code:

server.R

```
require(rCharts)
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$myChart <- renderChart({
    names(iris) = gsub("\\.", "", names(iris))
    p1 <- hPlot(input$x, input$y, data = iris, type = c("scatter"))
    p1$plotOptions(series = list(stickyTracking = FALSE))
    p1$addParams(dom = 'myChart')
    return(p1)
  })
})
```

ui.R

```
require(rCharts)
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("highcharts"),

  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput(inputId = "x",
     label = "Choose X",
     choices = c('SepalLength', 'SepalWidth', 'PetalLength', 'PetalWidth'),
     selected = "SepalLength"),
    selectInput(inputId = "y",
      label = "Choose Y",
      choices = c('SepalLength', 'SepalWidth', 'PetalLength', 'PetalWidth'),
      selected = "SepalWidth")
  ),
  mainPanel(
    showOutput("myChart", "highcharts")
  )
))
```

The app is online here: http://alligaator.at.mt.ut.ee:8100/users/metsalu/test2/. The problem is that if I hover over some of the points and then go out of the plot, the tooltip is still showing. I expected that stickyTracking = FALSE is turning it off. Am I missing something?

I have also tried to use followPointer option of the tooltip but no success.

Comment: This is functioning incorrectly due to an old version of highCharts clashing with jQuery. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25513790/no-auto-resize-of-yaxis-of-highcharts-in-shiny/25516138#comment39842882_25516138 . Hopefully the updated JavaScript library will be added to rCharts https://github.com/ramnathv/rCharts/issues/521 . Until then you can use `options(rcharts.cdn = TRUE)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to a clash between an old copy of the highCharts JavaScript library and the newer JQuery library . One temporary solution is to use a CDN rather then the local scripts:

```
library(rCharts)
library(shiny)
options(rcharts.cdn = TRUE)

runApp(
  list(ui = pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel("highcharts"),

    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(inputId = "x",
                  label = "Choose X",
                  choices = c('SepalLength', 'SepalWidth', 'PetalLength', 'PetalWidth'),
                  selected = "SepalLength"),
      selectInput(inputId = "y",
                  label = "Choose Y",
                  choices = c('SepalLength', 'SepalWidth', 'PetalLength', 'PetalWidth'),
                  selected = "SepalWidth")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      showOutput("myChart", "highcharts")
    )
  )
  , server = function(input, output) {
    output$myChart <- renderChart({
      names(iris) = gsub("\\.", "", names(iris))
      p1 <- hPlot(input$x, input$y, data = iris, type = c("scatter"))
      p1$plotOptions(series = list(stickyTracking = FALSE))
      p1$addParams(dom = 'myChart')
      return(p1)
    })
  })
  )
```